# Theoretical VS Practical running time evaluation

Tags: performance, algorithm, profiling

Suppose to have an algorithm of which we know the asymptotic behaviour, e.g. `O(n^4)`. We want to evaluate real world performance of that algorithm.

Now, a naive approach would be to run our algorithm many times, and plot running times against size of the input. We'll get a set of points in the x-y plane. How can we verify our implementation is truly `O(n^4)`? Could curve fitting be a good idea? There be other more effective methods?

Many thanks.

Comment: `n^4 = O(n^4)` and `0.0001 * n^4 + 10^100 * n^(pi) = O(n^4)`. Additionally, real-world running time depends on many things other than the algorithm. So...don´t start thinking in that direction at all. The most effective method is "looking at the code".

Comment: Actually, the most effective method is to profile and benchmark the code in realistic situations.  Analyzing any non-trivial piece of code can get very complicated, especially if you have to consider effects like memory hierarchy and instruction pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

What O(N^4) means is that no matter how big N gets, the running time will always be less than or equal to a curve of the form C+K*N^4, where C and K are arbitrary constants.
So, other than some sort of mathematical proof, possibly by recurrence relations, the only method is experimental.

So you throw a series of datasets at it, with N varying across a range of magnitudes, and plot the running time.
Then you fit curves of the form C+K*N^4, where you try to find minimal values of C and K, trying to convince yourself that the experimental data never exceeds the curve.

This doesn't prove anything, of course, because you are not able to try all values of N.
Even if you think you have a good curve, you can't assume there is no higher value of N that will bust your curve.
All you can say is that for values of N less than or equal to what you tried, the curve is good, and chances are reasonable that it remains good.